# fadeIn using $(document).ready( ) Causing a Noticeable Lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, document-ready

I'm relatively new to javascript and am building a web page. I'm using the Pikachoose slideshow as a banner on the page and I couldn't find a way to get it to fade in on load. When the page loads, the first image of the slideshow just loads straight up instead of fading in.

I decided to just use a fadeIn javascript function on the whole slideshow. Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pikachoose.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#slideshow').hide().fadeIn(1500);
        $("#pikame").PikaChoose();
    });
</script>
```

So basically it fades in and then Pikachoose starts up. BUT there is a noticeable lag on the fadein when the page loads. It works but it's a little choppy. Once it loads the slideshow works without any problems. Is there a way to delay the fadeIn slightly until the whole page loads so it's not getting tied up? I thought that was what the ready function accomplished though.

Why do you think that's happening? Any ideas? Thanks.

---

EDIT

Here's the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pikachoose.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#slideshow').hide().fadeIn(1500);
            $("#pikame").PikaChoose();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pikachoose.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul id="pikame" >
        <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="slideshow/purplebackground.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="slideshow/redbackground.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.pikachoose.com"><img src="slideshow/yellowbackground.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You might put the `.PikaChoose()` line in the [callback handler](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#callback-function) for `.fadeIn()` so it doesn't run until after the `.fadeIn()` completes. And you're probably better off using CSS to hide the `#slideshow` element instead of jQuery.

Comment: First i'd hide the #slideshow div with CSS, not jquery and remove the .hide() function completely. Then, what happens if you reduce the time of the fade to something less than 25 seconds?

Comment: I called the .PikaChoose() line in a function in the callback handler of .fadeIn() and it just showed nothing and then the Pikachoose slideshow just popped on the screen and started running like normal. Does that means my original code actually loads the Pikachoose slideshow first quickly, hides it and then fades the image in (the Pikachoose slideshow would have to load first so the first image of the slideshow would fade in)? I see what you all are saying about removing .hide() but now I'm struggling to figure out what's actually happening. I've  added the full code above. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Scott the duration for the `fadeIn()`effect detailed above is 1.5 seconds (1500 milliseconds).

Comment: @MxmastaMills what's probably happening is your `PikaChoose()` function is loading the slides and manipulating the DOM in tandom with jQuery's `fadeIn()`function, resulting in the apparent choppiness as the two functions fight over the DOM. Call `PikaChoose()` first, and only call `fadeIn()` upon its successful completion.

Comment: @Aaron I called the Pikachoose function first and then used .delay() to have it stop slightly after the PikaChoose function is called before beginning fadeIn but it didn't change anything (I set it at 3000 or 3 seconds; in theory it makes sense). Other than that I don't know how to ensure the 2nd function starts after the first is done, everyone who asks this question seems to get the answer that Javascript works sequentially and it shouldn't matter (but it does in this case). Are there any functions I can call that I'm not aware of besides .delay()? Could this problem be something different?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show us the page producing the issue? It sounds like there may be extraneous factors affecting your application's performance, and getting another set of eyes on the working code is probably the most efficient way to pinpoint them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.ready will fire when the DOM is ready, not when the page is loaded.

Before the page is loaded you may get undesired results when using animations because properties like width/height of the elements you like to animate may still be unknown. Also the images used by pikachoose may still not be loaded completely.

So you better use $(window).load() instead to execute your functions.

To have the slideshow hidden before the page is loaded, you may use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //add a class to the html-element to be able to apply
  //a different style if JS is enabled
    $('html').addClass('js_on');


    $(window).load(function (){
        $('#slideshow').fadeIn(1500);
        $("#pikame").PikaChoose();
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
 /* initially hide #slideshow when JS is enabled */
   html.js_on #slideshow{display:none;} 
</style>
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thanks. I'm still relatively new so I'm still learning the options of how to load pages and what the functions do. Big help.